# using oracle sql, how to convert each digit to sum 9

Tags: oracle

I need help to convert a mobilenumber as a way of masking, i need to convert each digit to 9. Please see my sample below:

sample:

1. 123456789
2. 111111111
3. 77771111

result:

1. 876543210
2. 888888888
3. 22228888

notice that if you add each digit for (sample and result) the result is 9.

Comment: What is the data type of the _mobilenumber_? Is it VARCHAR2? Is it NUMBER?

Comment: This is an awful way of masking the data; in fact it doesn't mask the data as it is a (very) simple substitution cipher and the original data can (easily) be reconstructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TRANSLATE`:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TRANSLATE( value, '1234567890', '8765432109' ) AS substitution
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '123456789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '111111111' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '77771111' FROM DUAL;
```

Gives:

> ```
> VALUE     | SUBSTITUTION
> :-------- | :-----------
> 123456789 | 876543210   
> 111111111 | 888888888   
> 77771111  | 22228888
> ```

## **DO NOT** use a substitution cipher to try to anonymise data.

However, this is not masking the data as it is (very) easy to get the original data back; you just put the substituted value back through the same translation and you have "unmasked" the data. So, if you are relying on this process to anonymise personal information then you have not achieved that goal as it is easy to reconstruct the original and de-anonymise the data.

```sql
SELECT value,
       TRANSLATE( value, '1234567890', '8765432109' ) AS substitution,
       TRANSLATE(
         TRANSLATE( value, '1234567890', '8765432109' ),
         '1234567890',
         '8765432109'
       ) AS reversed_substitution
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VALUE     | SUBSTITUTION | REVERSED_SUBSTITUTION
> :-------- | :----------- | :--------------------
> 123456789 | 876543210    | 123456789            
> 111111111 | 888888888    | 111111111            
> 77771111  | 22228888     | 77771111
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2d3059441c52c24ddd12b69415d4f048)*